# How to authorize documents in a website against a throttled external API

Tags: rest, authorization, throttling

I'm building a site serving secured documents to users. Access rights of those documents are stored in an external system that provides a throttled API. The external system cannot be accessed directly by the website users.

Some specificities regarding the securities:

- a new document is added once a week and active customers gain access to this document
- customer can obtain access to any old document that they currently cannot access (infrequent but can happen at any time)

There will be enough users at launch to reach the limit enforced by the external API. Beside mirroring the securities of the external system in my database, is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927984/throttling-a-rest-api-in-java

Comment: Is anything cacheable?

Comment: Everything is cacheable, the main things invalidating the cache are listed in the question: the new document each week and the infrequent changes that affect users requesting access to old documents.